# How can I get HttpContext inside an abstract class in ASPNETCore

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I have the following Repository:

```
public class TestRepository : WebCaller<Data>, ITestRepository
    {
        string connString = this.GetConnectionString();

       .... some code here
}
```

In my Repository I can do `Dependency Injection` to the constructor **without a problem**.

In my abstract class `WebCaller` I need to get access to `HttpContext` somehow, I was reading that you can `Inject` `IHttpContextAccessor` to get access to the context, but because this is an `Abstract` class, that also lives outside the Web project, I can't have a constructor.

I was trying to do this:

```
 public abstract class WebCaller<T> : WebRequest, IDisposable
    {
        //[Inject]
        public ITestRepository TestRepo
        {
            get
            {
                return this.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITestRepository >();
            }
        }

        ..... more code here
}
```

Was trying to use `Inject` attribute but was reading that is no longer available, so should be other way to pass `HttContext` to the abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a constructor on your abstract class. Just inject `IHttpContextAccessor` to it. Then any derived class will also take `IHttpContextAccessor` and pass it to its `base` constructor (your abstract class constructor). You can make the abstract class constructor `protected`.

Like:

```cs
public abstract class WebCaller<T> : WebRequest, IDisposable
{
    protected WebCaller(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
    }
}


public class TestRepository : WebCaller<Data>, ITestRepository
{
    public TestRepository(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) : base(contextAccessor)
    {
    }

    string connString = this.GetConnectionString();
    .... some code here
}
```